# How do I apply a VBA Macro to specific worksheets that contain a certain word in their name?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Macro code. I want to apply it to all worksheets that are called like "M&E Demand Calendar"? How would I do this? I am new to VBA. I assume that this code need to go into some sort of loop that will go through all the worksheets but im so confused on where to start. This Macro was created by Recording Macro in excel (as I'm not good at writing VBA yet)

```
Sub v49()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

     Worksheets("M&E Demand Calendar (S.S)").Select
    Cells.Select
    Cells.FormatConditions.Delete
    Cells.Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="High", _
        TextOperator:=xlContains
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Cells.FormatConditions.Delete
    Cells.Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="High", _
        TextOperator:=xlContains
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Cells.Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="Medium", _
        TextOperator:=xlContains
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 49407
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Cells.Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="Low", _
        TextOperator:=xlContains
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 15773696
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Cells.Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="Distress", _
        TextOperator:=xlContains
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 5296274
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False


    Sheets("Hotel Settings").Select
Range("I6").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "49"


End Sub
```

Comment: That all depends on what your "macro code" is, and you didnt post it.

Comment: @braX I have added the code, any help will be appreciated

Comment: I suggest you change the macro to accept a worksheet as an argument. Also _get rid of all the select_ statements. See [VBA Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices#t=201708241358024567181)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this can do the trick. If not, give more info:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim ws              As Worksheet
    Dim strName         As String

    strName = "M&E Demand Calendar"

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If InStr(1, ws.name, strName) > 1 Then MyMacro ws.name
    Next ws

End Sub

Private Sub MyMacro(str As String)

    Debug.Print str

End Sub
```

It checks whether the name of the worksheet contains the `strName` with the `InStr`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a loop that checks each sheets name then if it's the name you want then you can call this macro.  ie something like

```
sub v49SheetCheck()

dim counter1 as long

for counter1 = 1 to thisworkbook.sheets.count

    if 0 < instr(1,Sheets(counter1).name,"Thing to look for",vbTextCompare)_
    then 
        'this is here because all your code requires is that the target sheet be active
        sheets(counter1).activate 
        call v49 
    end if

next counter1

end sub
```

the only real change you'd have to make to the current macro you have then is to get rid of the first line. Though there are some coding best practices that I would suggest looking into. Ja72 was kind enough to link them in the comments on your post. but this should get you through most things

this is not case sensitive so it will see "THIS" and "this" as the same as well as "ThIs".  if that's relevant for some reason then you can change it "vbTextCompare" to "vbBinaryCompare" though I doubt that will be necessary.